# How to find Error in sharepoint 2010 Site and List Definitions

Tags: sharepoint-2010, error-handling, site-definition, list-definition

I am working with custom site,List,Fields and Contenttype. I have deployed my cusom list definition and i tried to create new item for my custom list there i am getting error with Correlation ID. There is no proper error log there. I dont no where the problem in is there any way to find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have changed the default location, the log files will be in the following directory on the SharePoint server:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS`

Open the log file that corresponds to the time given in the error, then search for the Correlation ID.